# Why do I have to enter two inputs for my code to start running?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using a while statement in my code, where, inside the while statement, the user inputs a number. To stop the program from looping, the user must input the word "stop". However, once I enter in a number, the output skips to another line without printing the statement I want it to print, and I have to enter my desired input again for the program to start looping. 
   The only time this problem DOES NOT occur is when the user inputs "stop" FIRST, then the code works fine.

This is to find the max, min, and mean of any amount of user-inputted numbers. I've tried changing the order of the else/if statements and the parameters for the said else/if statements, but nothing seems to work.

```
    boolean stopped = false;

    int numberAmount = 0;
    int invalidAmount = 0;

    double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    double mean = 0;        

    while(stopped == false)
    {   
        System.out.print("Enter a number (type "+"\""+"stop"+"\""+" to stop): ");
        String originalInput = userInput.nextLine();

        if(originalInput.equals("stop"))
        {
            stopped = true;
            invalidAmount ++;
            System.out.println(numberAmount+" numbers were entered with "+invalidAmount+" invalid inputs.");
        }

        else if(userInput.hasNextDouble())
        {
            double currentValue = Double.parseDouble(originalInput);
            max = Math.max(max, currentValue);
            min = Math.min(min, currentValue);
            mean = currentValue;
            numberAmount ++;
        }

        else if(originalInput.equals("stop") == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Not a number...");
            invalidAmount ++;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("The maximum is "+max+".");
    System.out.println("The minimum is "+min+".");
    System.out.println("The mean is "+(mean / numberAmount)+".");

    userInput.close();

}
```

}

For example, I expect the output after inputting 7 to be 
"Enter a number (type "stop" to stop):" on the next line(since the program loops to keep prompting for number input), where the user could then keep inputting numbers as they like.
   Instead, the actual output is a blank line under the original prompt for user input, where the user must input their desired input AGAIN for the program to start looping.

Comment: What does the method has**Next**Double() do? Does it look if the **previously read line** was a double? What does the javadoc say?

Comment: Ah, that's my problem, silly mistake. How would I check, in the else if statement, to see if the user input is a double?

Comment: You wouldn't read a line in the first place Instead, you would call hasNextDouble() before reading anything. If it returns true, you know there is a double and you read id using nextDouble(). If it returns false, you read the line and copare it with "stop".

Comment: @DanielLiu Raed the JavaDoc of Double#parseDouble, especially what it throws when an error occurs.

Comment: @JBNizet Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know the API, but I expect hasNextDouble reads another line. Check if originalInput is a double, don't read another line.

Comment: Yeah, just found that hasNextDouble is the problem, but I don't know how to check if  originalInput is a double or not.

Comment: Off the top of my head, pass it to the Double constructor and catch the number format exception.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't downvote your answer, it was downvoted before I saw it. I don't know why you got downvoted, your answer was the one that made me realize my mistake. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks! As @kaan says, you can accept it or upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should invert the logic of the code, assuming you are using the Scanner, try something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean stopped = false;

        int numberAmount = 0;
        int invalidAmount = 0;

        double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double mean = 0;

        while (stopped == false) {

            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a number (type " + "\"" + "stop" + "\"" + " to stop): ");

            if (userInput.hasNextDouble()) {
                double currentValue = userInput.nextDouble();
                max = Math.max(max, currentValue);
                min = Math.min(min, currentValue);
                mean = currentValue;
                numberAmount++;

            } else {
                String originalInput = userInput.nextLine();
                if (originalInput.equals("stop")) {
                    stopped = true;
                    invalidAmount++;
                    System.out.println(numberAmount + " numbers were entered with " + invalidAmount + " invalid inputs.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not a number...");
                    invalidAmount++;
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("The maximum is " + max + ".");
        System.out.println("The minimum is " + min + ".");
        System.out.println("The mean is " + (mean / numberAmount) + ".");

        // userInput.close();
    }
}
```

Basically you are checking first the input type, and only after you are collecting the value from the console. Doing it the way you have right now, you will always ask for the second input.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify in your code example what `userInput` is, but from the usage it looks to be an instance of `Scanner`. If you have a `Scanner` declared and then call `hasNextDouble()`, you will get a boolean result which fits with your usage – you have that as the condition in your `if` statement.

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean b = userInput.hasNextDouble();
```

What's missing from the picture is how `hasNextDouble()` works. Looking at the [Javadoc for Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()):

> *Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a double value using the nextDouble() method. The scanner does not advance past any input.*

In order to answer true/false for whether the next input is a double or not, the scanner has to wait for input from the user before it can proceed.

All of this to say: your code looks like it's behaving normally. If you don't want to wait for user input, you need to write your code to reflect that.

Comment: After implementing your suggestions, my code seems to run fine, thank you!

Comment: great ;-) remember to accept and/or vote up answers that helped. more detail in: [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)